# How to Set Variable Inside LaunchedEffect?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to set variable inside LaunchedEffect? It gives warning:

> Variable 'list' is assigned but never accessed.

> Wrapped into a reference object to be modified when captured in a closure.

```
@Composable
fun MyUi() {
    var list: List<String>
    LaunchedEffect("lorem") {
        list = listOf("lorem", "ipsum")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Composable
fun MyUi() {
    var list by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList<String>()) }
    LaunchedEffect("lorem") {
        list = listOf("lorem", "ipsum")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**